# Is there a possibility to change XmlNode prefix from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I use current code to create new xml document, then I try to change a prefix for `root` element, but I can't do it.

```
var node = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<root><first/></root>", "application/xml");
var root = node.documentElement;
root.prefix = "ds";
root.outerHTML(); // <root><first/></root>
```

I found description about `prefix` property. It should be set/get, but when I try to set `prefix` nothing happen.

Is there any other way to change prefix value for element?